# Android studio how to force the use of incompatible gradle plugins?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 8.4.0-alpha01) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 8.2.1
See Android Studio & AGP compatibility options.